# Upload large files to SharePoint Online using AddUsingPath

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to upload large files to SharePoint online using StartUpload, ContinueUpload and FinishUpload functions. This works fine for me when I use below code to add file:

```
using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
  fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
  fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
  fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
  uploadFile = parentFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
  using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer10MB))
  {
    // Call the start upload method on the first slice.
    bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
    fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
  }
}
```

But I am trying to use Files.AddUsingPath function instead of Files.Add to allow special characters in the file name. Specifically I see that if the file name has % character then above code renames the file as %25 . But while using AddUsingPath I get error as:

> Cannot access a closed Stream.    at
> System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()     at
> System.IO.MemoryStream.get_Length()     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.WriteMimeStream(ExecuteQueryMimeInfo
> mimeInfo, ChunkStringBuilder sb, Stream requestStream)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.SetupServerQuery(ChunkStringBuilder
> sb)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder
> sb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Code for AddUsingPath is as below:

```
if(first)  
    using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      FileCollectionAddParameters fileAddParameters = new FileCollectionAddParameters();
      fileAddParameters.Overwrite = true;
      uploadFile = parentFolder.Files.AddUsingPath(resourcePath, fileAddParameters, contentStream);
      using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer10MB))
      {
        // Call the start upload method on the first slice.
        bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added.
        fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
      }
    }    
else if(continue)
{
   using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer10MB))
   {
     // Continue sliced upload.
     bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Get error here Cannot access a closed Stream. when continue
     // Update fileoffset for the next slice.
     fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
   }
}
```

The difference I made here is add file using AddUsingPath if its first upload but continue upload and finish upload functionality remains the same.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer on another forum. I had to add

> uploadFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativePath(resourcePath)

inside if(continue). That worked for me.

```
else if(continue)
 {
     uploadFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativePath(resourcePath)
     using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer10MB))
     {
         // Continue sliced upload.
         bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
         ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Get error here Cannot access a closed Stream. when continue
         // Update fileoffset for the next slice.
         fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
     }
 }
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/244117/upload-large-files-to-sharepoint-online-using-addu.html